# SQL Select Query Question with Multiple Nested Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query question that I have no idea whether it's achievable.

***My database table structure:*** I have one table (`TABLE A`) is linked with second table (`TABLE B`) with the relationship of `ONE TO MANY`.

***Problem Scenario:*** The `ROW A` in `TABLE A` is linked with 2 rows (`ROWS A & ROW B`) in `TABLE B` with different value in `COLUMN A` . The next row `ROW B` in `TABLE A` is linked with only 1 row (`ROW C`) in `TABLE B`. **(Kindly refer to the following screenshot)**

[image]

***What I want:***

- I want to retrieve the result that show **column A value in `TABLE B`** and **primary key value of the row** **in `TABLE A`**.
- Not allow multiple row with same primary key. In other word, only one column value should retrieve from `TABLE B` (Even there's multiple rows in `TABLE B` that linked with one row in `TABLE A`). Due to this reason, when select the row in `TABLE B`, the `column A` that contain value of 2 will be taken first, the remaining rows will ignore. If the `column A` of each row in `TABLE B` doesn't contain the value of 2, then only it will select the row with value of 1.

Based on the above scenario, the expected result show look like this:

[image]

The following is the sample data:

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE tableA 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE tableB 
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    columnA INTEGER , 
    fkid INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (fkid) REFERENCES tableA(id)
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO tableA VALUES (2);

INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tableB VALUES (3, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here along with a join, and impose the ordering rules you want:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.id, b.columnA,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.columnA DESC) rn
    FROM tableA a
    INNER JOIN tableB b ON b.fkid = a.id
)

SELECT id, columnA
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo